# Regular expression to match float number pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the pattern I am looking to match with.
I have started something like this `^\d{1,}.^\d{1,}$` not sure to complete this.

- x
- x.x
- x cannot be zero (0 or 0.00 are not allowed but can be 1.02 or 0.123)
- Length of all x including decimals(if any) should not exceed 11 digits
- minimum 1 x is required
- only 1 decimal is allowed
- this is required field

Note: I am referring x as digit

I would like to use this **RegEx** both in **HTML5** `Pattern attribute` and in JavaScript `string.match("")`

clarity: I mean "1.02" is allowed, but "0" or "0.0" is not allowed

Comment: Yet another password validator?

Comment: If you say "x cannot be zero", do you mean "1.02" is not allowed, or just "0" or "0.0" is not allowed?

Comment: @devnull it seems yet another float number validator

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo A-ha! Innovative uses of regex never cease to amaze me.

Comment: @marsze 0 or 0.00 is not allowed

Comment: `x as digit` -- missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regexes is a good way to validate numbers, but if you want...

```
r = /^(?=.*[1-9])(?=.{1,11}$)([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]+)?$/
"1 1.2 0.2 100.2 00.1 0.00 0 234890324908324908342".split(" ").forEach(function(x) {
    console.log(x, r.test(x)) })

1 true
1.2 true
0.2 true
100.2 true
00.1 false
0.00 false
0 false
234890324908324908342 false
```

This is perhaps more accurate - doesn't accept trailing zeroes, as in `123.45600`:

```
r = /^(?=.*[1-9])(?=.{1,11}$)([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?$/
```

Comment: @KeluThatsall: ...and?

Comment: Thought it should be excluded also, nvm if it shouldn't

Comment: @thg435 thank you, this serves the purpose. Just curious, you said RegEx is not best for validating numbers, what are other options?

Comment: @HaBo: consider `parseInt` or `parseFloat` together with `isNaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
^(?!^0$)(?=.{1,11}$)(([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?)$
```

Comment: NO. with decimal length is going up to 12. it should be restricted to 11 including decimal 1.25484654565

Comment: I've corrected my regex with a Positive Lookahead `(?=.{1,11}$)`

Comment: Doesn't match `0.123`.